# Retrieve data with input type

Tags: php

Hello I would like to retrieve data into a single form without clicking submit forms,  it that possible ?

```
<?php
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE role='student' AND gradelvl='7' ORDER BY lrnno ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

and this is the html code for displaying value

```
<input type="text"  name="studname"><?php echo $row['studname']; ?> </input>
```

`studname` is included in `userinfo` table
Please help

Comment: yes, it is , it's called ajax.

Comment: Put the name in the `input` as a `value`. `<input type="text"  name="studname" value="<?php echo $_POST['studname']; ?>" />` and escape the input.

Comment: How does `$_POST['studname']` relate to the SQL?

Comment: $_POST['studname']  is one of the column of userinfo

Comment: please sir help me @chris85

Comment: `$_POST` is a form value. How is that coming in?

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
<input type="text"  name="studname" value="<?php echo $_POST['studname']; ?>"></input>
```

Comment: I omited some point of your pb. To see value from sql , you dont use $_POST. $_POST is used when u submit a post form. Use a cursor for example http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: oopss sorry I tried using '$row['studname']'  but no work

Comment: Dit you loop over the result like the example in the link i give you? Have look to function readDataForward in the doc i give u and try to print result before doing your work

Comment: <?php

  $sql = 'Your query';
  
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { echo $row['studname'];}